# Identification statistics

Tags: statistics

In an empircal study we would like to compute the mean of hours worked per day of the population in a country. The country consists of two regions A and B. 
X denotes the hours worked per person and the variable R is 0 for individuals from region A and 1 for B. 
Region A is twice as large as region B. Unfortunately we only observe all individuals from region A. Assume that there is a law which limits the maximum of hours worked per day to 12 hours, hence X can only take values from 0 to 12.

Is E(X) identifed? Show it formally.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This looks to be copy-pasted. I'll maybe come back if you edit this with your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$E[X]=E[X|R=0]·Pr(R=0)+E[X|R=1]·Pr(R=1) $$

$E[X|R=0]$ is observed and we know $Pr(R=0)=2/3$ and $Pr(R=1)=1/3$.

$E[X|R = 1]$ is not observed. Therefore, $E[X]$ is only partially identified.